# Is there any method to append test data with predicted data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 random array of tested dataset like `array=[[5, 6 ,7, 1], [5, 6 ,7, 4], [5, 6 ,7, 3]]` and 1 array of predicted data like `array_pred=[10, 3, 4]` both with the equal length. Now I want to append this result like this in 1 `res_array = [[5, 6 ,7, 1, 10], [5, 6 ,7, 4, 3], [5, 6 ,7, 3, 4]]`. I don't know what to say it but I want this type of result in python. Actually I have to store it in a dataframe and then have to generate an excel file from this data. this is what I want. Is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) for join arrays, convert to `Series` and then to excel:

```
a = np.hstack((array, np.array(array_pred)[:, None]))
#thank you  @Ch3steR
a = np.column_stack([array, array_pred])
print(a)
0    [5, 6, 7, 1, 10]
1     [5, 6, 7, 4, 3]
2     [5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
dtype: object

s = pd.Series(a.tolist())
print (s)
0    [5, 6, 7, 1, 10]
1     [5, 6, 7, 4, 3]
2     [5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
dtype: object

s.to_excel(file, index=False)
```

Or if need flatten values convert to `DataFrame`, `Series` and use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(array), pd.Series(array_pred)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
   0  1  2  3   4
0  5  6  7  1  10
1  5  6  7  4   3
2  5  6  7  3   4
```

And then:

```
df.to_excel(file, index=False)
```